# python return and print via a class

Tags: python

Why does first code print while the second doesn't? Is there something special about the return?

```
In [339]: class fraction:
    def __init__(self,top,bottom):
        self.num=top
        self.den=bottom
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)
   .....:

In [340]: f=fraction(3,8)

In [341]: print(f)
3/8
```

---

```
In [342]: class fraction:
    def __init__(self,top,bottom):
        self.num=top
        self.den=bottom
    def __str__(self):
        print str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)
   .....:

In [343]: f=fraction(3,8)

In [344]: print(f)
3/8

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-344-d478acf29e40> in <module>()
----> 1 print(f)

TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Comment: You need return in the second.

Comment: @badc0re: Ah, so that's it! I was sitting here squinting, trying to figure out how the two classes differ in the first place. |-}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `print()` on an object the interpreter calls the object's `__str__()` method to get its string representation.

`print(f)` gets "expanded" to `print( f.__str__() )`.

The print function here:

```
def __str__(self):
        print str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)
```

gets called, prints and returns `None`, so the outer print generates a `TypeError`:

So, yeah. You need to return a string in the `__str__()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix:

```
def __str__(self):
        print str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)
```

To:

```
def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)
```

Comment: He know that works - that is the only difference between the two tests.  He is asking why - what the difference is.

Comment: Well this doesn't looks like he is asking what is the difference, if am wrong he could made a comment. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

tells you that __str__ return non-string.
That's becouse str must return a string and in version:

```
def __str__(self):
    print str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)
```

You are printing result and returning **None**.
You have to return a string as you do in version 1